# htmlspecialchars & ENT_QUOTES not working?

Tags: php, htmlspecialchars

Basically on displaying data from MySQL database I have a `htmlspecialchars()` function below that should convert single and double quotes to their safe entity(s). The problem I'm having is on viewing source code, it is only converting `< > &` when I also need it to convert single and double quotes.

```
//sanitize data from db before displaying on webpage
function htmlsan($htmlsanitize){
    return $htmlsanitize = htmlspecialchars($htmlsanitize, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Then when I want to use for example I do:

```
htmlsan($row['comment']);
```

Can someone tell me why it's not converting single and double quotes?

**UPDATE**

What's strange is `htmlsan()` is used on comment in email and when I view source code of email it converts them, it seems that it won't convert the single/double quotes from the database on displaying on webpage. My database collation is also set to utf8_general_ci and I declare I am using utf8 on database connection etc.

Comment: Is it typo issue htmlan($row['comment']);? if, you are calling a different function

Comment: Hi, No it's not a typo, i just double checked, i made a typo when posting this question sorry but actual code there is no typo.

Comment: just calling `htmlsan($row['comment']);` will affect no variable in your code

Comment: Hi Col, what do you mean exactly? i thought that example i shown above would work, it certainly does on < > & but not on single/double quotes.

Comment: Dude. You desperately need to post **an exact and complete example**, not another portion of empty blab.

Answer (score 11):

How are you exactly testing it?

```
<?php

//sanitize data from db before displaying on webpage
function htmlsan($htmlsanitize){
    return $htmlsanitize = htmlspecialchars($htmlsanitize, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}

var_dump(htmlsan('<>\'"'));
```

... prints:

```
string(20) "&lt;&gt;&#039;&quot;"
```

My guess is that your input string comes from Microsoft Word and contains typographical quotes:

```
var_dump(htmlsan('“foo”')); // string(9) "“foo”"
```

If you do need to convert them for whatever the reason, you need `htmlentities()` rather than `htmlspecialchars()`:

```
var_dump(htmlentities('“foo”', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')); // string(17) "&ldquo;foo&rdquo;"
```

## Update #1

Alright, it's time for some proper testing. Type a single quote (`'`) in your `comment` database field and run the following code when you retrieve it:

```
var_dump(bin2hex("'"));
var_dump(htmlspecialchars("'", ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
var_dump(bin2hex($row['comment']));
var_dump(htmlspecialchars($row['comment'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

It should print this:

```
string(2) "27"
string(6) "&#039;"
string(2) "27"
string(6) "&#039;"
```

Please update your question and confirm whether you ran this test and got the same or a different output.

## Update #2

Please look carefully at the output you claim to be obtaining:

```
string(6) "'"
```

That's *not* a string with 6 characters. You are not looking at the **real** output: you are looking at the output as **rendered** by a browser. I'm pretty sure you are getting the expected result, i.e. `string(6) "&#039;"`. If you render `&#039;` with a web browser it becomes `'`. Use the *View Source* menu in your browser to see the real output.

Comment: Hi, it's not coming from Microsoft Word, it's data being retrieved from database and i typed it it myself when testing on keyboard, no copying or pasting. Also not sure why you say i should use htmlentities() as htmlspecialchars() should work according to PHP manual.

Comment: `htmlentities()` converts most non-ASCII chars into HTML entities while `htmlspecialchars()` only converts five specific characters. Are you sure your quotes are actual 7-bit ASCII quotes? How have you tested it?

Comment: Hi i just basically typed the quotes (single/double) in textarea using the keyboard. It's not complicated code and nothing that could be causing it a problem. I then created a blank page with a simple form and tried but again quotes not being converted. I also did not use the function and just tried by wrapping htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES) and still only converting the following 3 characters < > & . I tried htmlentities but it does not convert < > & for me and could be a problem as data needs to be cleansed on being displayed from database.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, much appreciate your time and help. This is what it printed out to screen by typing in a single quote   string(6) "'" string(2) "27" string(6) "'" string(2) "27" Thanks

Comment: Is suggested updating the question because you can format the output to make it readable, you could post the **exact code** you ran and the information is relevant for everyone. Never mind, see my second update.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Viewing source shows the same thing. I did this anyway view source obviously as browser will show it as it meant to but view source will show it in it's safe form. string(6) "'" string(2) "27" string(6) "'" string(2) "27"  Thanks

Comment: Hi Alvaro please read comment above. I have just noticed that it is actually working :O Reason why is i view source code using Firebug in FireFox and Firebug does not show it like if you go to "View Source" in on browser menu. I am awful sorry but never knew that Firebug worked showed it as webpage showed it, i thought it would have showed it like when you view source as if you done it via browser itself.

Comment: Well, yes, Firebug's `HTML` tab decodes HTML entities (I hadn't noticed it either). Anyway, I'm glad you got it working. At least you've learnt a couple of debugging tips :)

Comment: Yeah and thanks to your hard work. Much Appreciate your time and effort :)

Comment: Update 2 was helpful. Thanks for pointing that out. I was missing it too.

Answer (score 4):

When you view sourcecode using Firebug, Firebug shows it like the web browser displays it, I thought it would have shown the source code the same as if you went to View Source in Browser Menu Bar. A headache learnt and will be remembered. Thanks everyone for your valuable time and input.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Testing it through FireFox view source is a total dud with `htmlentities($str,ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");` and the single quote appears as a single quote. If you have Chris Pedrick's Web Developer extension and do the view source through that, you see the single quote display as `&#039;`. Moral of the story, use a raw view source that doesn't purtify your page HTML so you can tell things are working.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will make any difference but have you tried removing the `$htmlsanitize`.

```
function htmlsan($htmlsanitize){
    return htmlspecialchars($htmlsanitize, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for replying much appreciate it, for some reason it still won't convert single and double quotes yet it will convert < > &

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. My database is with utf-8_unicode_ci and my html charset utf-8, and htmlentities only converted everything but quotes. I thought that having same charset in both db and html would work fine, but it didn't. So I changed the charset on the html to iso-8859-1 and it worked. I don't know why, but it worked. My db is still with utf-8_unicode_ci.

Comment: This was the problem I was having. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
htmlentities($htmlsin, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

or

```
mb_convert_encoding($htmlsan, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8");
```

Would probably do what you want them to.

Comment: Hi, first option is what i already have and second option does not convert possible malicious tags like javscript etc to safe entity like < > .