# html entities not converting special characters

Tags: php, character, html-entities

I'm using htmlentities which is converting characteres with accents, but it is not converting this type of quotes “. Instead the browser shows a weird symbol with a question mark �

How can I convert these kind of characteres that display as symbols?
e.g. The book called �Hello Colors� is on the table.

I've tried this commands but it's not working:

```
htmlentities($message);
htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
htmlentities($message, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
htmlentities($message, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
```

Thank you.

I just realised something weird, if I do the following

```
echo $message; die();
```

to show a white page for debugging the quotes are displayed! 
So what is happening? Why it's not displaying correctly in the website page? :S

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8"> is this there in your webpage header

Comment: I think you have missed the charset specification there in the browser , Any ways I posted the same because I was sure about it

Comment: utf8_encode($message); ???

Comment: I have <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and it still shows the symbol for those quotes

Comment: This "�" means you try to display data as UTF-8 which actually **is not** UTF-8. So, @RobertRozas is right, use `utf8_encode($message)` first

Comment: I tried this htmlentities(utf8_encode($messsage)); but it's not working. I get another result though: Â�Hello ColorsÂ�

Comment: I just realised something weird, if I do the following echo $message; die(); to show a white page for debugging the quotes are displayed! So what do you think is happening? :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have missed charset specification in your browser ,

try adding `<meta charset="UTF-8">` this in your webpage head section . I previously had an issue like this to display multilingual text in UTF -8  I did the same to solve this issue .

hope this helps

BTW

for HTML 5 
`<meta charset="UTF-8">` works

in case of HTML 4

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

and in case of XML you have to specify

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Here is the place where you can get all information

[Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

There are several ways to setup the content charset , even you can setup your server also to render always utf-8 you can read here for more info in the [server setup](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset) section

**EDIT : -**

After conversation with you in the comment section ,

**Your problem is with Joomla**

you tested by putting 
charset ISO-8859 in the webpage and it works this clearly proves that you are getting content in ISO not in UTF-8

probabily your mysql Database is not in UTF-8 I think and that is why it is sending ISO text to front , you can change the DB to UTF-8 general-ci or ISO latin1 which ever is feasible and that works I suggest you to change DB to utf-8-general-ci since you already have html pages with header set to utf-8 and that will solve your problem .

Also if you cant change the DB then you already know that its in ISO charset so change all your Joomla template header to ISO charset .

which looks like this

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

OR

in php

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');
```

by removing your charset utf-8 declaration which is existing .

Comment: I have <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> and it still shows the symbol for those quotes

Comment: @Snitram Okay if you are using linux can you try preparing a sample script with the htmlentities function and a sample string. And run that  and see what its rendering for you . This is to make sure whether htmlentities is doing its job or not

Comment: im using windows microsoft IIS as the web server. htmlentities is working since it converts the characteres with accents like ù á ì but it's just not converting the quotes “

Comment: Okay then you can look into this SO posting here it has some solutions for the similar problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722727/htmlspecialchars-ent-quotes-not-working

Comment: I just realised something weird, if I do the following echo $message; die(); to show a white page for debugging the quotes are displayed! So what do you think is happening? :S

Comment: @SnitramSD That means the generated content is not UTF-8 its `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">` can  you try

Comment: Yes it works if I do that. But I'm using joomla so I had to change a joomla core file to change the charset. Is it possible to use any function that displays the string using the iso-8859-1 instead of having to modify the page's charset? thank you.

Comment: I tried using this htmlentities($message, ENT_COMPAT, "ISO-8859-1") but it doesn't work. :S

Comment: Gotcha your mysql Database is not in UTF-8 i think and that is why it is sending ISO text to front , you can change the DB to UTF-8 general-ci or ISO latin1 which ever is feasible and that works I suggest you to change DB to utf-8-general-ci since you already have html pages with header set to utf-8 and that will solve your problem

Comment: Well the problem is that I don't have that kind of permissions to change the database. :S It's a Microsoft SQL Server database. No other possible way? :S thank you.

Comment: put this line in your joomla template folder `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1');' index.php file it solves problem you dont need to add this every where

Comment: @SnitramSD I added you problem is with Joomla from comment here and solution also to my posting

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, it worked for me:

```
<?php
$message = "“Hello Colors“";
$message = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $message);
echo htmlentities($message);
?>
```

Result:

```
&quot;Hello Colors&quot;
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was simple:

When I typed it in the Elements tab of the developer panel, it didn't work. But when I typed it into my code and reloaded the page, it worked.

That's because the browser converts it to the right character when it loads the page, but doesn't convert it when you just type in the entity id in the developer panel.