# htmlentities function breaking a while loop

Tags: php, iis

I have a piece of code which is driving me crazy please help!

Basically I have result set from a database returning 3 rows of data, the data in the field I'm interested in is as below:

row 1 - "the Retention Release Date;"
row 2 - "where applicable, any later due date for Retention release under clause 4·15·2·3; or"
row 3 - "the date of issue of the Contractor's statement under clause 4·6·2 or, in default, the last date for issue of that statement."

The array is `$result_set` and the associative key is `['subsubclausedesc']` so the code I am running is:

```
while($result_set = $database->fetch_array($result)) 
{
    echo htmlentities($result_set['subsubclausedesc']);
}
```

The problem I am having is that only the 1st row is being returned to the screen, if I echo without htmlentities I get all 3 rows, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `htmlentities($result_set['subsubclausedesc'], ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8");` and see if it makes any difference. Also, make sure that you've set UTF-8 as the charset on your page using `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your head.

Comment: use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: @ZahidulHosseinRipon mysql_real_escape_string is only used on input, not output.

Comment: Wayne thanks for the response but still doesn't work, my page head does include the <meta charset="utf-8"> I am wondering if this is some kind of setting in the php.ini file, as I had this running on wamp on a local machine, now trying on a server running IIS8 and ran into the problem.

Comment: Zahidul the database I am using is sql server so I do not believe using mysql_real_escape_string would work?

Comment: Okay I have now discovered that it is the middle dot · that is causing the problem, although I do not understand why this is the case, any ideas?

Comment: Found the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007956/html-entities-not-converting-special-characters

For some reason you need to use utf8_encode prior to htmlentities.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with stripslashes

```
  while($result_set = $database->fetch_array($result)) 
    {
    echo htmlentities(stripslashes($result_set['subsubclausedesc']));
    }
```